# Distribute rows evenly over the height of a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

[`TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) contains the handy attribute `android:stretchColumns="*"` to distribute column width evenly over the size of the table. Can the same be done for rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TableLayout` extends `LinearLayout`, so you can just define your [`TableRows`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) as such:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
```